# is structKeyExists in coldfusion case sensitive?

Tags: data-structures, coldfusion, key, case-sensitive

A simple query if the function `structKeyExists()` used in coldfusion is case-sensitive or not about its 'key'. I did not find a straight answer and wanted to post it here

Comment: I posted the answer so its a direct answer to the doubt. I have even mentioned it.

Comment: Might have been faster to simply test it. Now the question is indexed by google and will by found by people who also would like to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just my 2 cents on a bit round-the-bush answer to a simple doubt if structKeyExists in coldfusion is case sensitive or not about its key. The usual search did not give me any straight answers so here it is. Nope its not case sensitive. That is:

```
<cfset foo={}>
<cfset structinsert(foo,"Yoosaf","Boy") />
<cfif structKeyExists(foo,"YOOSAF")>
  <cfoutput>#foo.yoosaf#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
<cfif structKeyExists(foo,"yOOSAF")>
  <cfoutput>#foo.yoosaf#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Both the IF condition will return me true

I hope this helps

Comment: Most things in ColdFusion are case-insensitive. The docs usually mention case sensitivity only, if functions/operators are in fact aware of the case.

Comment: first time working on a scenario like this, your answer saved my time.

Comment: Just wondered tody about case sensitivity in StructKeyExists and was surprised https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structkeyexists.html does not speak about it.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally use hashmaps; very similar to a struct but they retain creation order (unlike structs which are orderles) and they have case-sensitive keys. When generating structs, I often use theStruct["caseSensitiveKey"] format so that the keys are not all UPPERCASED when serialized to JSON.

Comment: HashMap's do not have a guaranteed order. Perhaps you are thinking of [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which do maintain insertion order?

Comment: Sorry... I mean to indicate linkedHashMap.  (I responded using my mobile device & didn't look it up when responding.)

I've encountered issues in the past where an object returned from Java functions like an array or struct, but is a specialized type... like the LinkedHashMap.  I believe that this would be the only case where addressing a "ColdFusion struct" would require case-sensitivity.

Comment: Yep. Though java [Maps and Lists can be used *like* CF structures and arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7884.html) - in general the java objects are (almost) always case sensitive and are frequently data type sensitive as well. That is a common gotcha.